# Google API gapi.cliet.request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, google-api

I am using Freebase JS api to fetch topic details. This is a simple function for that:

```
function simpleTopicDetail(topicIds){
    path = 'freebase/v1/topic' + topicIds;
        var opts = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'path': path,
            'params': {'filter':'/common/topic/article'}
        };
    var request = gapi.client.request(opts);
    request.execute(onFinalSuccess);

    var onFinalSuccess = function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //do something with data
        //parsing JSON resp to get a node value.
    }
}
```

On debugging I see, it goes to onFinalSuccess and then nothing! Skips to the end. What's wrong here? 
**NOTE** I'm using it in conjuction with YT API. It's a sepearte function though. Can it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are refering to the call back function before it's assigned.
Try:

```
function simpleTopicDetail(topicIds){
    path = 'freebase/v1/topic' + topicIds;
        var opts = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'path': path,
            'params': {'filter':'/common/topic/article'}
        };
    var request = gapi.client.request(opts);
    request.execute(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //do something with data
        //parsing JSON resp to get a node value.
    });
}
```